# no captcha recaptch overlay not display entirely

Tags: recaptcha

I put the no-captcha recaptcha in a popup (FancyBox), everything is fine.(recaptch1.PNG) But when the user click on the checkbox the captcha image overlay is not show entirely. (recaptch2.PNG).

My question, can we place automatically the overlay the manner the user can see the directive. (recaptch3.PNG) Or can we resize the overlay to fit the iframe in the popup so everything can be seen?

Any suggestion?

recaptch1.PNG
[image: recaptch1.PNG]

recaptch2.png
[image: recaptch2.png]

recaptch3.PNG
[image: recaptch3.PNG]

Comment: Try setting your recaptcha container to a higher `z-index`

Comment: it's will not work because the recaptcha is in an iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found a solution. After a lot of search i have found this link: https://www.geekgoddess.com/how-to-resize-the-google-nocaptcha-recaptcha/

It's resize the container of the recaptcha V2, but not resize the overlay because google inject the overlay on the page not in the container. Because i have found that google inject the overlay on the page, I can now customize the overlay. So I use the technique on the previous link but I affect to the class "gc-bubbleDefault".

I add this in my css and this solve my problem:
.gc-bubbleDefault{transform:scale(0.82);transform-origin:0;-webkit-transform:scale(0.82);transform:scale(0.82);-webkit-transform-origin:0 0;transform-origin:0 0; 0}

It's a solution that don't work on all browser version (not old ie), but it's work for me.

[image]